# Get specific listview rows based on condition

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have a listview with diffrent entries (see figure (A).  I would like to extract some specific rows based on a condition. So far, i have this code:

```
 private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    ArrayList listing = new ArrayList();

    for (int i = 0; i < listView2.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        string columnOne = listView2.Items[i].Text;
        string columnTwo = listView2.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text;
        int numb = int.Parse(listView2.Items[i].SubItems[2].Text);
        string columnThree = listView2.Items[i].SubItems[3].Text;

        if(numb >= 2)
        {
            listing.Add($"{columnOne},{columnTwo},{numb},{columnThree}");
        }
    }
    foreach (string item in listing)
    {
        listView2.Items.Clear();
        ListViewItem listItem = new ListViewItem();
        var separ = item.Split(',');
        listItem.Text = separ[0].Trim();
        listItem.SubItems.Add(separ[1]);
        listItem.SubItems.Add(separ[2]);
        listItem.SubItems.Add(separ[3]);

        listView2.Items.Add(listItem);
    }
}
```

[image]

I get figure (B), but normally i should get figure (C).  How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you shouldn't clear listview in foreach loop. do it once:

```
listView2.Items.Clear();
foreach (string item in listing)
{
    // listView2.Items.Clear();
    ListViewItem listItem = new ListViewItem();
    var separ = item.Split(',');
    listItem.Text = separ[0].Trim();
    listItem.SubItems.Add(separ[1]);
    listItem.SubItems.Add(separ[2]);
    listItem.SubItems.Add(separ[3]);

    listView2.Items.Add(listItem);
}
```

Comment: Great!! Thank you very much, "ASh" !!

Answer (score 1):

Removing the non matching items from the list makes more sense here. For your problem, execute a backward loop, try to convert the text of the third subitem to integer value using the [`int.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=net-5.0) method, and remove the `ListViewItem` if the value is less than 2.

```cs
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (var i = listView2.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (int.TryParse(listView2.Items[i].SubItems[2].Text, out var num) && num < 2)
        {
            listView2.Items.RemoveAt(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Yet, if you want to get a list of matching items:

```cs
// +
using System.Collections.Generic;

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var items = new List<ListViewItem>();

    for (var i = 0; i < listView2.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        if (int.TryParse(listView2.Items[i].SubItems[2].Text, out var num) && num >= 2)
        {
            items.Add(listView2.Items[i]);
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

Or LINQ way:

```cs
// +
using System.Linq;

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var items = listView2.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>()
        .Where(x => int.TryParse(x.SubItems[2].Text, out var num) && num >= 2)
        .ToList();

    // ...
}
```

As a side note, using the `ArrayList` class [is not recommended](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist?view=net-5.0#remarks), use the [`List<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-5.0) class instead.

Comment: Pretty beautiful code snippets!! Thank you very much for your support and your help, "dr.null"!  Now everything works fine again...  : )